# ¿Secuencia if? ¿Recursividad?

Tags: c++

[image: Este es el enunciado del problema]

***CABE DESTACAR QUE APENAS ESTOY EN PR2 Y HAY MUCHAS COSAS QUE TODAVIA NO SE, DISCULPEN MI IGNORANCIA***

(Tiene que resolverse con recursividad)

Buenas este es mi codigo en el cual intento resolver el problema de la imagen de arriba, en el cual no entiendo por que en mi codigo solo me muestra dos caminos posibles cuando, ejemplo usando n=3, tendria 0123,013,023. mientras solo me muestra 0123,023. Una ayuda por favor gracias

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void caminos (int,int);

int main(){
    int i=0,n=0;
    cout<<"Inserte tamaño de la Rayuela: ";
    cin>>n;
    caminos(i,n);
return 0;
}
void caminos (int i,int n){
    if(i<=n){
        cout<<i;
        caminos(i+1,n);
        if(i+2<n){
             cout<<i;
             caminos(i+2,n);
            }
    }
    else{
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo no se que es la Rayuela, pero en base al resultado que usted pone que deberia de obtener puede que tenga u olvidara usar `=`, `<=` en lugar de `<` en el segundo `if` de caminos:

```
if(i+2<=n){
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void caminos (int,int);

int main(){
    int i=0,n=0;
    cout<<"Inserte tamaño de la Rayuela: ";
    cin>>n;
    caminos(i,n);
return 0;
}
void caminos (int i,int n){
    if(i<=n){
        cout<<i;
        caminos(i+1,n);
        if(i+2<=n){
             cout<<i;
             caminos(i+2,n);
            }
    }
    else{
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

[test](http://ideone.com/NsvIh0)

[test](http://ideone.com/1Pr0sI)

Comment: Hola amigo @AngelAngel , la rayuela es un juego https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayuela_(juego)

Comment: @Elenasys Saludos! si ahora se cual gracias al link jaja, creo que puede ser de los juegos que eh visto que mas nombres diferentes tiene como puedo ver en el link de la wikipedia, y eso solo para el español. Saludos